# Modify HTML tags in a *ngFor loop based on a variable in Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm working in Angular 4 and I would like to modify the html tags based on a variable in my *ngFor loop. This is the code that I'm trying to build:

```
<mat-card-content *ngFor="let question of questionGroup.profileQuestion class="mat-elevation-z2">

  <!-- I would like to do something like this in a *ngIF and isQASideBySide 
       is a boolean value -->  
  <div class="container" *ngIf="questions.isQASideBySide THEN fxLayout.xs='row' ELSE fxLayout.xs='column'" fxLayoutGap.xs="0" fxLayoutGap="10px">

      <div fxFlex="50%" fxFlexOrder="1" style="padding:10px">
         <p>
           {{ question.profileQuestionText }}
         </p>
      </div>

      <div fxFlex="50%" fxFlexOrder="1" style="padding:10px" >
         <!-- INPUT CONTROLS ....-->  
      </div>
  </div>
</mat-card-content>
```

Comment: `<mat-card-content *ngFor="let question of questionGroup.profileQuestion class="mat-elevation-z2">` <--- You're missing a " after `profileQuestion`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using property binding with ternary operator like:

```
[fxLayout.xs]="question.isQASideBySide ? 'row' : 'column'"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, I still needed to modify other part of my code with the same concept.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your syntax for ***ngIf**,
I think you are missing a delimiter at the end of the condition in ngIf before **then** and **else**.

Please refer to this link,

[ngIf Syntax Angular Docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#using-non-inlined-then-template)

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

**MODIFIED CODE**

It worked here is the OP's final code (moved from the question itself):

```
<mat-card-content *ngFor="let question of questionGroup.profileQuestion class="mat-elevation-z2">           
  <div class="container" [fxLayout]="question.isQASideBySide ? 'row' : 'column'" fxLayoutGap.xs="0" fxLayoutGap="10px">

      <div [fxFlex]="question.isQASideBySide ? '50%' : '100%'" fxFlexOrder="1" style="padding:10px">
         <p>
           {{ question.profileQuestionText }}
         </p>
      </div>

      <div fxFlex="50%" fxFlexOrder="1" style="padding:10px" >
         <!-- INPUT CONTROLS ....-->  
      </div>
  </div>
</mat-card-content>
```